# Use Asus Transformer Prime as USB Debugger

Tags: android, debugging, transformer-model

I am thinking about buying the Asus Transformer Prime, to start developing on android. Currently I am borrowing a Motorola Xoom to develop, and that has a Micro USB port, that I can plug into, and use it to debug my apps. From what I can tell the Asus Transformer Prime does not have such a port. Can I even use this as my debugging device, or would I be making a $500 mistake?

Thank you in advance for all of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformer Prime does not have any micro USB port, the station has one so you will need to buy it with

[Source](http://eee.asus.com/en/eeepad/transformer-prime/specification/)

Edit: Thinking about it, the station is the only way to charge the tablet... so it can not be bought  without it... I guess

Edit 2: Just updated my Android SDK Manager to 4.0.3 (an hour to figure it out) and it works great !

Comment: the tablet can be bought and charged without the base (keyboard). The usb charge cable that connects to the base can also be plugged into the tablet directly.

Answer (score 0):

Before spending $500, I would take the Micro USB cable to a Best Buy retailer and see it physically plugged into the device by one of their employees.  This is what I did before buying my tablet for debugging.

Comment: I dont beleive it even has a micro usb. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

No But it comes with its own connector. Good luck getting it to work with Flashbuilder. I can't get it to see my device.  In another perspective, not flashbuilder, it can load the device fine.

Answer (score 0):

I heard there was a USB to micro-hmdi dongle you could buy that would work. Here are two That say they should work:
[http://www.amazon.com/Transformer-TF101-Prime-TF201-Replacement/dp/B006NVLDKG/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1329078209&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006NVLDKG)

[http://www.amazon.com/Aftermarket-Product-Charging-Replacement-Transformer/dp/B006N3L5SE/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1329078209&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006N3L5SE)

Answer (score 0):

YES.

I'm using Ubuntu.  Simply use the supplied connector, plug it into the tablet (or dock if it's connected) and the USB into your computer.  Make sure you have USB debugging checked in Settingss|Developer options.